# Got this error: nw_protocol_get_quic_image_block_invoke dlopen libquic failed

Tags: ios, json, swift, codable, decodable

I was trying to connect my API data to view it in the cell but it seems that I can't get my response and it's always `== nil`
The code below describes the Country.SWIFT // Model.SWIFT // Response.SWIFT which is showing how can I get my JSON response using Codable
and CountryCell.SWIFT is showing how I used it to call the API
The link to the API image:

[image: pic]

**Country.SWIFT**

```
struct Country: Decodable {
    
    var CountryName = ""
    var CountryImage = ""
    var objectId = ""


// MARK: - Coding Keys
enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case CountryName = "CountryName"
    case CountryImage = "CountryImage"
    case objectId = "objectId"
}

//MARK: - Json Decoder

init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    
    let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    // Parsing our attributes
    self.CountryName = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .CountryName)
    self.CountryImage = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .CountryImage)
    self.objectId = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .objectId)

}

}]
```

**Model.SWIFT**

```
protocol ModelDelegate {
    
    func countriesFetched (_ countries: [Country])
    
}

class Model {
    
    //MARK: - Vars
    var delegate: ModelDelegate?
    
    // MARK: - Get Countries
    func getCountries () {
        // URL Object
        let url = URL(string: Constants.API_URL)
        guard url != nil else {return}
        
        // URL Session object
        let session = URLSession.shared
        
        //Data Task from URLSession object
        
        let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in
            
            if error != nil || data == nil {
                print(error!.localizedDescription)
                return
            }
            print(data!)
            
            do {
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                let response = try decoder.decode(Response.self, from: data!)
                
                if response.items != nil {
                    
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.delegate?.countriesFetched(response.items!)
                    }
                  
                }
            }
            catch {
                
            }
        }
        
        // start data task
        dataTask.resume()
    }
}
```

**Response.SWIFT**

```
 struct Response: Decodable {

    var items: [Country]? = []
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        var itemsContrainer = try decoder.unkeyedContainer()
        self.items = try itemsContrainer.decode([Country].self)
        
    }
    
    
}
```

**CountryCell.SWIFT**

```
class CountryCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    
    //MARK: - Vars
    var country: Country?
    
    //MARK: - Outlets
    @IBOutlet weak var imageViewCountryOutlet: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var lblCountryNameOutlet: UILabel!
    
    //MARK: - Creating Cell

    func generateCell (_ myCountry: Country) {
        self.country = myCountry
        
        guard self.country != nil else {  return }
        lblCountryNameOutlet.text = country!.CountryName
        
        guard self.country!.CountryImage != "" else {return}
        
        let url = URL(string: self.country!.CountryImage)
        
        guard url != nil else {return}
  
        let session = URLSession.shared
        
        let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in
            
            if error == nil || data != nil {
                if url!.absoluteString != self.country!.CountryImage {
                    
                    return
                }

                let image = UIImage(data: data!)

                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.imageViewCountryOutlet.image = image
                    
                }
            }
            
        }

        dataTask.resume()
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Can please print `data` parameter in `getCountries` method, you can try this `String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!`

Comment: Did you recently updated to Xcode 12? It seems that there is a problem with this last version that throws libquic exception

Comment: yeah I already did it

Comment: nw_protocol_get_quic_image_block_invoke dlopen libquic failed is not an an error and is irrelevant to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need for the wrapping `Response` type, decode the list of countries directly:

```swift
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
let items = try decoder.decode([Country].self, from: data!)
```

In your code, when you ask in `Response` for `unkeyedContainer`, the expected JSON structure would need additional nested array.

Check decoding errors in the `catch` block with

```swift
do {
...
}
catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it sounds bit absurd but in my case, by using class instead of struct and declare all attributes with public var worked for me.